# Loading Data into Multiple Comboboxs C# Winforms

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, caching, combobox

Looking for a bit of advice, I have WinForms application with a Search screen with multiple comboboxes. These comboboxes are databound by pulling the data from a database and populating a DataTable which is then bound to the box.

At present on Form Load, each Combobox makes a call to the database using a Stored Procedure to get the data, this data changes very rarely.

Looking at both usability and performance, which is the best way to populate this data?

Should I create an XML document that is updated from the database or Keep it as it is?

I'm really open to ideas here!

Comment: Why do you think the performance of a database query is critical here? And are there plausible scenarios where the database is unreachable? If not, I wouldn't change anything. Without knowing your environment, it's hard to recommend anything.

Comment: Why would you update a XML document from database. If you want to use it why not bind it to a dataset. It would be easier.

Comment: @germi - This database is only accessible on a private network and should never be unreachable.

Comment: @NilayVishwakarma The only reason I looked at an XML document was a way of caching the data to save the round trip time.

Comment: Okay, so the database is (presumably) near by, answers quickly and almost always available. In that case I wouldn't bother with caching anything. It would only introduce overhead and more opportunity for bugs to sneak in. If on the other hand your network (or database server) is at capacity and performance / usability of your application suffers, that would be a valid reason to cache the results...

Comment: @JammoD [Decide wisely](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/xmldatabase/entry/xml_versus_relational_database_performance17?lang=en)